# Variable in AJAX url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I use a variable within an AJAX call URL?

So far I have the following:

```
id = $(this).children('span.title').attr('data-id');

$("#test").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/ + id/ .gameBox-Ops");
```

There is something wrong with the way I have declared the url but being relatively knew to Ajax I am a little unsure where I am going wrong.

Just to point out the .gameBox-Ops is not part of the URL, it is the class of the container I am trying to call with AJAX

Comment: I'm not too sure about why you're adding .gameBox-Ops but notice some concatenation you can add that might get your further than where you are. $("#test").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/ " + id + " / .gameBox-Ops");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#test").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "/ .gameBox-Ops");
```

Not related to AJAX, your string concatenation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a variable, you have to escape the string to concatenate it into it.

```
$("#test").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/"+id"+/ .gameBox-Ops");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use proper string concatenation. Also I am not sure why you have `.` on last part.

```
id = $(this).children('span.title').attr('data-id');
$("#test").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "/.gameBox-Ops");
```

Comment: the .gameBox-Ops at the end is the class of the container I am trying to call with AJAX